# No type was found that matches the controller named ''

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, asp.net-web-api, odata

We are developing api for our SQL Server tables. The WebApiConfig class is as follows:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<CRMUser>("User");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName:"ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

The controller is as follows:

```
public class UsersController : ODataController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    OnlineStoreEntities db = new OnlineStoreEntities();
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    public IEnumerable<CRM_vwUser> Get()
    {
        return db.CRM_vwUser;
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }

}
```

But we got error while browsing  this url "http://localhost:50246/User". The error is as follows:

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50246/user'.


No type was found that matches the controller named 'User'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You controller name is `UsersController`  (with an S) and in your URL you set `../User` as well as in

```
 builder.EntitySet<CRMUser>("User");
```

Try setting `Users` in your URL and Entity Set,or change Controller to `UserController`